# Django comments being spammed

Tags: django, spam, django-comments

I am using the built in comment system with Django but it has started to be spammed.  Can anyone recommend anything I can use to stop this such as captcha for django etc.  I'm looking for something that I can use along with the comment system rather than replacing it.

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Do you use all the fields of the built in comments-form? There is a honeypot-field to help prevent spam (see [the docs](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/comments/#id1)). Would [django-simple-captcha](http://code.google.com/p/django-simple-captcha/) help?

Answer (score 3):

see if [this snippet](http://www.djangosnippets.org/snippets/1255/) can help you to use Akismet on you Django comments

Answer (score 2):

Depending on the popularity of your site, I decreased my spam 100% by putting up a static captcha with no obstructions.  If your site isn't hugely popular, spammers won't waste their time trying to crack your captcha.  I mainly bring this up, because these days it seems like captchas are becoming harder and harder for humans to read consistently (might just be me, but the Google captcha usually takes at least two tries).